# iOS 8, PhotoKit, PHAsset, unique identifier

Tags: ios, ios8, photokit

Working on an app that is iOS 8, and handles a lot of photos, I need to uniquely identify PHassets but cannot find any property to use? I found one property
on

```
 PHObject/localIdentifier
```

documented here

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/PHObject/localIdentifier

Is there any way to have a unique ID on PHAsset? PHObject is a bit heavier to use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, that's the only property to use.

However, `PHObject` implements both `-hash` and `-isEqual:` methods. It also conforms to `NSCopying` protocol, which means that it can be used as a key in dictionaries and can be put in sets, etc. It also continues to work when you reload `PHAsset` objects. This is a huge win over `ALAsset` class. The implementation of `-isEqual` is much faster than the `localIdentifier` property and can be safely used on the main thread. You could use profiler to get an idea of what's under the hood.

Comment: Hi, so PHAsset does have .hash property, but do I need to implement my own isequal? for PHAsset?

Comment: No, PHAsset implements both, as well as NSCopying protocol.